# Dynamic structured Content in a ScrollView

Tags: objective-c

I have a DetailContentView with a ScrollView and different Elements in it.

For Example i have to add 3 Headlines and 3 Texts programmatically into a UIView called "thisShadowBox".

How could i add the Elements in an easier way? This is my first try, but after this i need the Hight of the Text to place the second Element, right?

```
UITextView *addThisText = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 305, 200)];
[thisShadowBox addSubview:addThisDescription];
```

I hope there is another Way. Something like in HTML/CSS:

```
<div style="background:#CCCCCC">
 <p>Textblock1</p>
 <p>Textblock2</p>
</div>
```

To use HTML-Code in a UIWebView is not really an alternative.

Answer (score 0):

```
- (CGSize)sizeWithFont:(UIFont *)font constrainedToSize:(CGSize)size lineBreakMode:(NSLineBreakMode)lineBreakMode; // NSTextAlignment is not needed to determine size
```

Use this method to get the height of the string content and implement by the simple math add logic

use this method to get the height

```
-(CGFloat)getStringHeightOfString:(NSString *)inputString withFont:(UIFont *)font with:(CGSize)maxSize
{
  CGSize size = [inputString sizeWithFont:font
                               constrainedToSize:maxSize
                                   lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];
    return size.height;

}
```